# Rails saves value to database beyond limit restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I have this schema in Rails 6

```
create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title", limit: 100
t.text "description"
t.string "slug", limit: 20
t.integer "requests"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.index ["slug"], name: "index_fields_on_slug", unique: true
t.index ["title"], name: "index_fields_on_title", unique: true
```

And inside rails console:

```
field = Field.new
field.slug = 'a' *25
field.save
```

And the entry is saved succesfully inside fields table.
Why? I have a limit of 20 for :slug. Shouldn't that fail without validate in the model?

Comment: in development sqlite3 (localy)

Comment: SQLite doesn't really have `varchar(n)` or `char(n)` types, it just has `text`. You can create a column with a `varchar(20)` type but it will still be `text`. Don't use SQLite for development, install the same database that you're going to deploy on and use that for development and testing. There are all kinds of differences between databases that will trip you up so develop, test, and deploy with the same database.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Ok, i'll try that. 
Im also experiencing some issues with add_foreign_key :tables1, :tables2.
Im guessing it needs table2_id column to exist and it doesnt wotk with table2's id column?

Comment: Sounds right. You could also use `t.references ... foreign_key: true` for the that.

Comment: with t.references i can create a foreign key targeting the id (default PK) of a table?
That was my first implementation but I wasn't confident or sure about it, deleted it and tried with add_foreign_key which failed.

Comment: `t.references` will add the necessary column and the FK.

Comment: you were right. After replacing sqlite3 with mysql the restrictions on the database level worked fine, without validate. I lost plenty of time troubleshooting sqlite3.

Comment: SQLite has its place and it has been incredibly useful to me over the years. Unfortunately its fast-and-loose nature gets in the way sometimes.